# How can i can get Strings from Enum after using toString()

Tags: java, enums, tostring, vaadin8

I am creating a list from which the user can select from using Vaadin8. I want to get the values from the Enum but the string values with spaces not the Element Names.

```java
public enum CustomerStatus {
    
    ImportedLead {
        public String toString() {
            return "Imported Lead";
        }
    }, 
     NotContacted{
        public String toString() {
            return "Not Contacted";
        }
    }, 
     Contacted{
        public String toString() {
            return "Contacted";
        }
    }, 
     Customer{
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer";
        }
    }, 
     ClosedLost{
        public String toString() {
            return "Closed Lost";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the list created to select from the Enum elements:

```java
private NativeSelect <CustomerStatus> status = new NativeSelect<>("Status");
```

And here are 3 lines I tried that did not work:

```
status.setItems(CustomerStatus.values().toString());

//
status.setItems(CustomerStatus.valueOf(CustomerStatus.values())); 
//
status.setItems(CustomerStatus.ClosedLost.toString(), CustomerStatus.Contacted.toString() , CustomerStatus.Customer, CustomerStatus.NotContacted, CustomerStatus.ImportedLead);
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `value` property:

```
  public enum CustomerStatus {

  ImportedLead("Imported Lead"),
  NotContacted("Not Contacted"),
  Contacted("Contacted"),
  Customer("Customer"),
  ClosedLost("Closed Lost");

  private final String value;

  CustomerStatus(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public static CustomerStatus fromValue(String value) {
    CustomerStatus result = null;
    switch(value) {
      case "Imported Lead":
      result = CustomerStatus.ImportedLead;
      break;
      case "Not Contacted":
      result = CustomerStatus.NotContacted;
      break;
      case "Contacted":
      result = CustomerStatus.Contacted;
      break;
      case "Customer":
      result = CustomerStatus.Customer;
      break;
      case "Closed Lost":
      result = CustomerStatus.ClosedLost;
      break;
    }
    if (result == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided value is not valid!");
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
status.setItems(Arrays.asList(CustomerStatus.values()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could give your `enum` the following:

```
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                String result = super.toString();
                return result.replaceAll("([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1 $2");
            }
```

Comment: OP has already implemented the `toString()` method on each enum value; this doesn't change what they already have.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: only *one* override is necessary. It's not necessary to repeat the method.